# How could i get this grid with Boostrap?

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

What i want is to make this divisions using Bootstrap and AngularJS

[image]

What i don't know how to do is to make the divisions, i was thinking to split the container in 3 columns of 4. Also want to know if can i split the container in two columns of 6 and overlap another div to make the SECTOR 3?

This is what i said before, but this doesn't give me what i want.

```
<div class="container" contenteditable="false">
    <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-default">Button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-default">Button</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT 1**

Also would like to know how to get this responsiveness when loading the site on a smartphone.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IohdsXRfQU3iUUPPYpiA?p=preview)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="content-body">
      <div class="section1 pull-left">section 1</div>
      <div class="section2 pull-right">section 2</div>
      <div class="section3">section 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Reset */
html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }


.container { 
  display: table; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
}

.content { 
  display: table-row; 
  height: 100%; 
}

.content-body { 
  display: table-cell; 
}

.section1 {
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  display:block;
}

.section2 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: blue;
}

.section3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  background: yellow;
}
```

For responsive style changes you need to add a media query:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
        .section3, .section2, .section1 {
            display:block;
            position: relative;

        }
        .section3 {
            height: 10%;
            width: 100%
        }
        .section2 {
            height:60%;
            width: 100%
        }
        .section1 {
            height: 30%;
            width: 100%
        }

    }
```

Comment: Really thanks, I made an edit to the original post, i would like to make it responsive too. If you could help me i'll set your answer as correct answer :D